# Problems accessing Cassandra through Kundera remotely with authorization turned on

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, cassandra, kundera

I try to connect my play application to Cassandra DB. I tried this tutorial: http://recipes4geeks.com/2013/07/06/play-nosql-building-nosql-applications-with-play-framework/

The difference in my setup is that cassandra is not on my localhost, but in one of my servers in the internet. To keep my cassandra installation secure i also used password authorization instead of the AllowAll authorization used on local installs.

So i added those two lines to my persistance.xml:

```
    <property name="kundera.username" value="user" />
    <property name="kundera.password" value="passwd" />
```

However i have problems running the application. It seems that i cant get authorized:

```
[KunderaException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)] 
user.setLastName("Smith");
```

24        user.setCity("London");

25

26        em.persist(user);

27        em.close();

28        return ok("User 0001 record persisted for persistence unit cassandra_pu");

29    }

30

31    public static Result find()

So i am wondering what do i have to do to log in to Cassandra? All the examples on the net i could find are only for this localhost/allowEverything scenario. What do i have to do, to get this example running in a production environment with real servers and real passwords?

Answer (score 0):

This is enabled for PelopsClientFactory, a tickt is open and soon will be fixed in 2.7.

-Vivek

Comment: a fix has been added for this on current trunk branch